# In javascript, how can I pass a function with parameter to be called later?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I have the following method in javascript:

```
  ShowPopupWithCallback("MyController/Load", alertCallback);

  function alertCallback()
  {
        alert("Ready");
  }  

  function ShowPopupWithCallback(url, callbackFunc)
  {
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $("#myDialog").html(data);
            callbackFunc();
        }, "html");

  }
```

this works fine but I now want to pass in a parameter from the calling ShowPopupWithCallback method.  something like:

```
  ShowPopupWithCallback("MyController/Load", alertCallback("My Message"));

  function alertCallback(message)
  {
        alert(message);
  }  

  function ShowPopupWithCallback(url, callbackFunc)
  {
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $("#myDialog").html(data);
            callbackFunc();
        }, "html");

  }
```

but this DOESN"T seem to work as the alert is called right away (not after the ajay returns)

What is the right way to pass in a function to a method that includes it own parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use anonymous function for that:

```
ShowPopupWithCallback("MyController/Load", function(){ alertCallback("My Message");});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind` to perform [partial function application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

```
ShowPopupWithCallback("MyController/Load", alertCallback.bind(null, "My Message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass it as an additional argument

```
 function alertCallback(message)
  {
    alert(message);
  }  

function ShowPopupWithCallback(url, msg, callbackFunc)
  {
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        $("#myDialog").html(data);
        callbackFunc(msg);
    }, "html");
  }

ShowPopupWithCallback("MyController/Load", "My Message", alertCallback);
```

Comment: This makes the whole thing much less flexible and pollutes the API in my opinion.

Comment: plalx don't think it should be downvoted because of that it's still a valid answer to the question.